# "Global Use" In C#

Tags: c#

I'm not sure what to title this, so that's why I used quotations. Bare in mind, I'm very new to C#.

I'm just creating a basic Notepad in C# VS.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Notepad_Project
{
    public partial class notepadMain : Form
    {
        public notepadMain()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private RichTextBox GetRichTextBox()
        {

            RichTextBox rtb = null; // initialising null
            TabPage tp = tabControl1.SelectedTab;

            if (tp!=null)
            {
                rtb = tp.Controls[0] as RichTextBox;

            }

            return rtb;

        }

        private void newToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            TabPage tp = new TabPage("New Document"); // Allows for new tab creation
            RichTextBox rtb = new RichTextBox(); // Allows for new richtext box object
            rtb.Dock = DockStyle.Fill; // Applys dock with RTB
            tp.Controls.Add(rtb); // Tabs RTB
            tabControl1.TabPages.Add(tp); // Add tabs to tab control

        }



        private void cutToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            GetRichTextBox().Cut();

        }

        private void copyToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            GetRichTextBox().Copy();

        }

        private void pasteToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            GetRichTextBox().Paste();

        }

        private void openToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Stream myStream;

            if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK) {

               if((myStream=openFileDialog1.OpenFile())!=null) {

                    string filename = openFileDialog1.FileName;
                    string readfiletext = File.ReadAllText(filename);

                    TabPage tp = new TabPage("New Document");
                    RichTextBox rtb = new RichTextBox();
                    rtb.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
                    tp.Controls.Add(rtb);
                    tabControl1.TabPages.Add(tp);
                    rtb.Text = readfiletext;

                }

            }

        }

        private void saveToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            SaveFileDialog savefile = new SaveFileDialog();
            RichTextBox rtb = new RichTextBox();
            savefile.Filter = "Plain Text (.txt)|*.txt|Batch File (.bat)|*.bat|Visual Studio (.vbs)|*.vbs";

            if (savefile.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) {

                rtb.SaveFile(savefile.FileName, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);

            }

        }
    }
}
```

I basically, in short want to use `RichTextBox rtb = New RichTextbox();` once and be able to declare it everywhere else, like a global variable. I've seen that you can use classes for this, but I'm unsure on how to implement it this way. If you notice, you can see that I have to declare `RichTextBox rtb = New RichTextBox();` everytime I add a new function or so on.

If I was to remove the `RichTextBox rtb = New RichTextbox();` from this section:

```
 private void saveToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        SaveFileDialog savefile = new SaveFileDialog();
        RichTextBox rtb = new RichTextBox();
        savefile.Filter = "Plain Text (.txt)|*.txt|Batch File (.bat)|*.bat|Visual Studio (.vbs)|*.vbs";

        if (savefile.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) {

            rtb.SaveFile(savefile.FileName, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);

        }

    }
```

I will then obtain this error too: `The name 'rtb' does not exist in the current context`

So, how would I implement and use this globally in C#? This is also so I can learn how to shorten certain things and keep it clean, efficient and tidy.

Comment: declare RichTextBox rtb = new RichTextBox(); out of the methods and inside the class, that way you can access the rtb in all methods of that class. if you want to access this rtb out of the class, create provider method inside the class that will expose the rtb to outer world.

Comment: Take a look at `GetRichTextBox()`: you use one RichTextBox per tab. Wherever you need a reference to rtb you should call `GetRichTextBox()`, as you did for copy/cut/paste actions. So replace `RichTextBox rtb = new RichTextBox();` in saveToolStripMenuItem_Click method with `var rtb = GetRichTextBox()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You creating controls dynamically so in your case you don't need to remove that line. You need to GET active tab rich text control and you have method for that. 
Of course you can replace `GetRichTextBox()` method with property like this:

```
private RichTextBox ActiveRichTextBox
{
    get
    {
        RichTextBox rtb = null; // initialising null
        TabPage tp = tabControl1.SelectedTab;

        if (tp!=null)
        {
            rtb = tp.Controls[0] as RichTextBox;
        }

        return rtb;
     }
 }
```

and use it in your code like this:

```
private void saveToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SaveFileDialog savefile = new SaveFileDialog();
    savefile.Filter = "Plain Text (.txt)|*.txt|Batch File (.bat)|*.bat|Visual Studio (.vbs)|*.vbs";

    if (savefile.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) {

        ActiveRichTextBox.SaveFile(savefile.FileName, RichTextBoxStreamType.PlainText);
    }
}
```